# Aviary crashes on Android L (5.0)

Tags: java, android, android-5.0-lollipop, aviary

Was just testing my app and found out that after I upgraded my Nexus 5 to Lollipop/5.0, the Aviary SDK I use in it crashes big time.

In a google search I found an SO question asked yesterday with the exact same problem, but that question has been deleted by the user (I was able to view it through Googles cache).

### It said:

> When I run my project on Android L it crash every time with error: 11-20 09:27:38.560: A/art(13974): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI GetFieldID called with pending exception 'java.lang.NoSuchFieldError' thrown in int com.aviary.android.feather.headless.moa.Moa.n_init(android.content.Context, java.lang.String, int):-2
>   anyone has any solution for this? thanks. ps, it fine with sdk <= 4.4

My problem is exactly the same - It worked pre-5.0 and on my other phone (Galaxy S2 with 4.1.3) it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest aviary sdk both for Android studio and Eclipse is available at Aviary web site.

Gradle SDK - Version 3.6.3-Gradle

ANT SDK - Version 3.6.3-ANT

I was able to test the eclipse version integrated and tested on lollipop emulator. There was no any crash.

Please give feedback, if tested on actual Lollipop android device.

Aviary website link [Aviary android sdk](https://developers.aviary.com/docs/android).

Answer (score 2):

I'm getting the same exact error. It seems like you have three options here.

Delve into the library source code and try to fix the bug yourself

Wait for Aviary/Adobe to patch it

Check the current Build.VERSION.SDK_INT and disallow Aviary if it is greater than 19.

Comment: Glad I'm not the only one at least. I coincidentally got a news letter e-mail from Aviary, saying that a new SDK is coming in december, so I'm hoping that'll fix it. If you download Aviarys own photo app, it runs with no problems on Lollipop.

Comment: Yes @DavidK. I'm also searching for the solution of crash and got this link. Thanks for the post. Thanks ynnadkrap for answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've found out that updating to the latest Aviary SDK version fixes the 5.0 issue - but also requires the developer to switch from ANT to Gradle = From Eclipse to Android Studio. 
It took me a very long time to get my projects working and building correctly in AS, but now it appears to be working - including Aviary.

Comment: is it working with Android Studio 1.0 ? What does your compile look like? using the last SDK 3.6.3, gradle it doesn't doesn't work. Looking forward to reading from you

Comment: I'm getting this error: Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Theme.Base.AppCompat.Dialog.FixedSize'.
Can it have something to do with the main base theme?

Comment: I'm using Android Studio 1.0.1 (latest), and Aviary SDK 3.4.3 (But about to upgrade to latest).

Comment: The crash is only fixed on the Gradle sdk?

Comment: No idea, I migrated to Gradle, so it's not possible for me to test ANT.

Comment: Has anyone of you found the solution to @stephane issue as even i am facing the same error. I am using Android Studio 0.8.9 and i am using the following compile statement     compile 'com.aviary.android.feather.sdk:aviary-sdk:3.6.3'

Comment: use adobe creative sdk!

Comment: I am having the same error as @Stephane. Any workaround?

Comment: @jeraldo, see my answer below...!

Answer (score 0):

Switch to adobe creative sdk https://creativesdk.adobe.com/

the Aviary library is now embedded there